# How to dispose a screen BEFORE the new screen is initialized, during go_router navigation?

Tags: flutter, riverpod, flutter-go-router

I have a `Screen A` that is calling `context.pushReplacement(ScreenA.route)`, which means it is calling `pushReplacement` on itself. The problem is, the new copy of `Screen A` is initialized BEFORE the old `Screen A` is disposed.

This is a problem since I am using Riverpod, and I need the `Provider` (with `autoDispose`) of `Screen A` to be disposed, and THEN recreated on the new copy of `Screen A`. What is happening is since the new `Screen A` is being created before the old one is disposed, the provider is never *not* being listened to, and therefore never being disposed. So the new `Screen A` is being created with the same instance of the provider, which creates problems in my application.

Is there any way to have the new screen that is being created with `context.pushReplacement` to wait until the old screen is disposed so it can be created?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could manually reset the required provider via `ref.invalidate(provider)` or via `ref.refresh(provider)` if you need the value of that provider (or to do a rebuild immediately).

```dart
context.pushReplacement(ScreenA.route);
ref.invalidate(provider);
```